# Refetch Graphql data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, graphql, graphql-js, relayjs

I have the Base Component which will have a QueryRenderer to fetch data for header, food items list, filtering options. In the render method, i would like to display the Header, FoodList and a FilterSidebar . Now when on click of a item in FilterSidebar, i am changing the state in redux , which in turn is used as variables for the QueryRender. The QueryRender refetches the data again with the new filters. The problem is since Header and Filtersidebar is also inside renderer method of queryrender, All the components get refreshed. Is there any way to handle this situation where only the listing changes based on new variables.

Comment: Maybe implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) for the components in question? With redux you would usually build smaller components and connect them to the store so that you don't have to do that.

Comment: Also is this really a problem? The only impact should be performance, otherwise you are doing something wrong. Make sure you are optimising a bottleneck before you are optimizing at all. The level of your question does not indicate, that you are at the stage where you should be optimizing React renders.

Comment: the mail goal is to have root QueryRenderer[limiting graphql api call to single request] and it will provide data to child fragment container. However, child component can change the filter option hence the query variables needs to be changed. Changing the query variables re renders all the component